# How to count words in a list?

Tags: python

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
# Imported libraries for future use.
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.nytimes.com').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response,"lxml")

host = []
#created empty list to append future words extracted from data set.
for story_heading in soup.find_all(class_="story-heading"):
    story_title = story_heading.text.replace("\n", " ").strip()
    new_story_title = story_title.encode('utf-8')


    parts = new_story_title.split()[0]

    i=['a','A','an','An','the','The','from','From','to','To','when','When','what','What','on','On','for','For']
    if parts not in i:
        host.append(parts)
    else:
        pass
#now i have to calculate the number of repeated words in the file and calcute the number of repeatation.    
print host
```

let me know how to calculate the number of repeated words in list we created.
actually am pretty confused about the above code too.
if anyone can explain what I did mistake in it, it would be grateful.

Comment: You can do that with default [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: What about case sensitivity? Is "What" == "what" or shall they be treated as different values?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Counter` method in *collections* module:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import Counter
import urllib2
# Imported libraries for future use.
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.nytimes.com').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response,"lxml")

host = []
#created empty list to append future words extracted from data set.
for story_heading in soup.find_all(class_="story-heading"):
    story_title = story_heading.text.replace("\n", " ").strip()
    new_story_title = story_title.encode('utf-8')


    parts = new_story_title.split()[0]

    i=['a','A','an','An','the','The','from','From','to','To','when','When','what','What','on','On','for','For']
    if parts not in i:
        host.append(parts)
    else:
        pass
#now i have to calculate the number of repeated words in the file and calcute the number of repeatation.    
print Counter(host)
```

Output:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Counter({'North': 2, 'Trump': 1, 'U.S.': 1, 'Kasich-Cruz': 1, '8': 1, 'Court': 1, 'Where': 1, 'Your': 1, 'Forget': 1})
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `count`

```
d = {i: host.count(i) for i in set(host)}
print(d)
```

Comment: Note that this will count duplicate items multiple times. The result will be the same, but it takes longer. You should iterate over a set (collection without duplicates) of the elements of host instead of the host list directly for better performance, especially if there are many list items that occur more than once.

Answer (score 1):

Using a dictionary comprehension iterating over a set of the elements:

- **case-sensitive version** ("What" != "what"):

  ```
  occurrences = { item: host.count(item) for item in set(host) }
  ```
- **case-insensitive version** ("What" == "what"):

  ```
  occurrences = { item: host.count(item) for item in set(item.lower() for item in host) }
  ```

  The dictionary keys will also be the lowercase elements in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the below code snippet which does not use list comprehension. I feel this should be simple to understand.

```
host = ['Hello','foo','bar','World','foo','Hello']
dict1 = {}
host_unique = list(set(host))
for i in host_unique:
    dict[i] = host.count(i)
```

Comment: You are missing some indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
lst = ['hi', 'Hio', 'Hi', 'hello', 'there' ]
s = set()
map(lambda x: s.add(x.lower()), lst)
print(len(s))
```

OR

```
lst = ['hi', 'Hio', 'Hi', 'hello', 'there' ]
s = set()
for item in lst:
    s.add(item.lower())
print(len(s))
```